# Sort numbers into groups so that the difference of their sums is minimal

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I found a few threads that were similar however I believe mine is a bit unique. This will be difficult to write so please bear with me.

I have a strain of 10 accounts, each account has a static number that can not be split up. I have 3 employees that need these accounts split as even as possible. They cannot share an account.

For example:

```
(A)lpha    = 15    
(B)eta     = 30    
(C)harlie  = 22    
(D)elta    = 19    
(E)cho     = 28    
(F)ranklin = 3    
(G)roto    = 7    
(H)enry    = 28    
(I)ndia    = 38    
(J)uliet   = 48
```

The total sum is = 238. In the perfect world, 2 people would get 79 and one person would have 80. However, remember we cannot break apart an account so we would need to add accounts together to get as close to evenly spread as possible.

I need a formula for this since situations like this occur regularly and it takes some time to figure this out. I believe this would be best executed with a helper column.

The closest I have come to is:

```
FHJ  = 79
ABCG = 74
DEI  = 85
```

But since this is reoccurring and can happen over even more accounts, I need something I can reuse over and over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Another less complex but approximated solution would be to**

1. sort your accounts from highest to lowest number.
2. Start sorting the numbers into 3 groups (A, B, C)

   - starting with the 3 highest numbers (`48|J`, `38|I`, `30|B`) sorting to group A, B and C
   - next highest number (`28|E`) goes to the group with the lowest sum (C)
   - next highest number (`28|H`) goes to the group with the lowest sum (B)
   - and so on …

You should end up with this:

[image]

Which is different from your manual solution but closer. If you see the differences:

- Solution from above: `81 - 77 = 4`
- Your manual solution: `85 - 74 = 11`

This algorithm is an approximation, it will not *always* find the *best* solution but if the difference between the lowest and highest number is not too large then the result is very close to the best solution.

Comment: This is very clever. I like this as well. This will work really well.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as a [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). You could try implementing the pseudo-polynomial time algorithm from the Wikipedia page. You'll have to modify it for 3 partitions instead of 2.

```
INPUT:  A list of integers S
OUTPUT: True if S can be partitioned into two subsets that have equal sum
1 function find_partition(S):
2     n ← |S|
3     K ← sum(S)
4     P ← empty boolean table of size (floor(K/2)+ 1) by (n + 1)
5     initialize top row (P(0,x)) of P to True
6     initialize leftmost column (P(x, 0)) of P, except for P(0, 0) to False
7     for i from 1 to floor(K/2)
8         for j from 1 to n
9             if (i-S[j-1]) >= 0
10               P(i, j) ← P(i, j-1) or P(i-S[j-1], j-1)
11            else
12               P(i, j) ← P(i, j-1)
13    return P(floor(K/2), n)
```

Comment: That is complex but perfect for what I need. Thank you :)

Comment: Just to mention that with bigger numbers this algorithm is impractical for the *k*-way multi-partitioning problem with *k* > 2 because it then takes `O(n(k − 1)m^(k − 1))` memory where *m* is the largest number in the input: making it impractical even for *k* = 3 unless the inputs are very small numbers.