Finding optimal cut-off points for dividing a variable into equal groups considering ties in which quantiles do not work
I have a variable x and I want to divide it into three groups with equal observations. However, using quantiles did not result in the most equal groups due to ties, as quantiles cut-off points may result in ties being allocated into more than one group. I am looking for a function or algorithm that can find the best cut-off points while ensuring that ties are not split across multiple groups.
x = c(26, 34, 27, 26, 38, 40, 34, 28, 27, 36, 29, 30, 29, 44, 30, 
      34, 32, 30, 26, 29, 34, 32, 38, 27, 35, 29, 28, 34, 26, 27, 27, 
      30, 27, 28, 27, 28, 28, 27, 29, 29, 28, 29, 29, 28, 29, 29, 28, 
      27, 29, 27, 36, 34, 34, 39, 34, 31, 31, 33, 35, 31, 31, 32, 37, 
      38, 32, 31, 28, 33, 33, 28, 27, 27, 30, 31, 32, 28, 27, 31, 36, 
      27, 33, 31, 34, 31, 35, 38, 37, 36, 39, 33, 33, 28, 41, 34, 35, 
      37, 37, 41, 32, 37, 30, 34, 38, 30, 40, 35, 31, 30, 30, 29, 29, 
      30, 29, 35, 28, 27, 27, 27, 29, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 26, 28, 28, 
      27, 29, 29, 27, 27, 27, 27, 29, 27, 28, 27, 28, 34, 29, 28, 28, 
      28, 29, 38, 33, 39, 28, 27, 28, 27, 29, 34, 29, 32, 70, 26, 29, 
      43, 48, 30, 30, 27, 26, 29, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 
      27, 28, 28, 38, 52, 26, 31, 56, 29, 29, 36, 28, 35, 32, 34, 35, 
      28, 27, 37, 26, 26, 32, 26, 27, 30, 28, 28, 30, 29, 30, 29, 29, 
      28, 26, 33, 39, 26, 31, 27, 28, 30, 30, 28, 28, 29, 26, 27, 26, 
      29, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 29, 
      27, 26, 28, 28, 27, 27, 28, 27, 28, 28, 30, 27, 30, 28, 32, 34, 
      28, 27, 28, 28, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 28, 27, 27, 28, 27, 
      27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 26, 27, 27, 30, 28, 27, 30, 30, 
      42, 26, 27, 40, 33, 29, 29, 29, 52, 58, 44, 32, 43, 30, 27, 38, 
      30, 27, 30, 27, 31, 39, 35, 32, 32, 34, 45, 31, 44, 42, 29, 29, 
      30, 30, 50, 30, 33, 31, 35, 27, 28, 27, 28, 55, 28, 28, 28, 27, 
      27, 28, 29, 27, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 29, 34, 45, 27, 
      29, 61, 38, 62, 29, 36, 36, 30, 31, 45, 27, 30, 28, 29, 44, 45, 
      42, 52, 50, 52, 42, 38, 42, 32, 27, 37, 40, 52, 27, 36, 38, 39, 
      34, 30, 29, 34, 29, 26, 35, 43, 33, 40, 35, 33, 41, 61, 45, 35, 
      52, 50, 38, 43, 29, 35, 38, 39, 31, 28, 28, 29, 34, 27, 30, 32, 
      28, 26, 28, 27, 26, 29, 27, 26, 29, 29, 27, 29, 27, 27, 29, 27, 
      30, 29, 25, 30, 27, 29, 29, 30, 30, 27, 30, 28, 28, 27, 29, 29, 
      30, 29, 27, 28, 28, 28, 29, 28, 28, 27, 28, 29, 28, 29, 27, 28, 
      28, 28, 30, 27, 27, 28, 26, 28, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 
      28, 27, 28, 27, 35, 27, 27, 28, 29, 27, 27, 28, 26, 27, 28, 28, 
      28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 32, 27, 28, 28, 29, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 30, 
      29, 28, 25, 27, 28, 30, 28, 30, 30, 28, 30, 30, 28, 29, 30, 28, 
      28, 26, 27, 28, 45, 36, 40, 28, 50, 45, 30, 45, 40, 30, 45, 45, 
      29, 45, 35, 40, 40, 30, 30, 30, 45, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 35, 
      34, 49, 40, 30, 61, 35, 40, 30, 36, 35, 29, 27, 48, 28, 27, 27, 
      26, 27, 29, 27, 26, 27, 31, 27, 27, 28, 29, 28, 27, 28, 29, 38, 
      30, 26, 36, 40, 58, 57, 30, 33, 56, 35, 39, 37, 38, 46, 37, 39, 
      39, 45, 35, 46, 58, 65, 60, 45, 32, 36, 43, 32, 68, 39, 28, 31, 
      27, 28, 27, 37, 38, 30, 30, 28, 36, 45, 28, 26, 28, 28, 28, 27, 
      26, 28, 27, 26, 26, 27, 28, 31, 32, 37, 35, 29, 33, 35, 29, 41, 
      32, 36, 29, 28, 28, 28, 37, 36, 37, 35, 31, 32, 30, 27, 31, 32, 
      31, 33, 28, 33, 29, 27, 28, 31, 28, 31, 28, 34, 27, 27, 28, 27, 
      27, 27, 27, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 28, 26, 31, 26, 29, 31, 29, 29, 
      30, 29, 30, 31, 32, 29, 30, 27, 32, 27, 26, 31, 31, 31, 27, 27, 
      33, 27, 28, 28, 28, 26, 27, 27, 28, 30, 27, 27, 30, 29, 26, 27, 
      28, 27, 26, 26, 28, 27, 26, 28, 28, 26, 28, 27, 29, 27, 28, 28, 
      26, 26, 29, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 26, 25, 27, 29, 30, 36, 40, 28, 
      38, 26, 27, 27, 50, 27, 45, 27, 28, 26, 25, 35, 35, 44, 30, 27, 
      31, 27, 28, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 35, 33, 30, 28, 28, 29, 29, 36, 
      32, 36, 34, 32, 28, 28, 29, 28, 28, 32, 30, 35, 33, 36, 32, 30, 
      32, 36, 34)

quantile(x, probs = c(0.333, 0.666))
#> 33.3% 66.6% 
#>    28    31

l = cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, 28, 31, Inf))
table(l)
#> l
#> (-Inf,28]   (28,31] (31, Inf] 
#>       387       185       246

#using different cut-off points yielded more equal groups
l = cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, 28, 32, Inf))
table(l)
#> l
#> (-Inf,28]   (28,32] (32, Inf] 
#>       387       214       217

#again using different cut-off points which yielded more equal groups
l = cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, 27, 32, Inf))
table(l)
#> l
#> (-Inf,27]   (27,32] (32, Inf] 
#>       222       379       217

Created on 2024-10-07 with reprex v2.1.1
Edit:
I think the word "equal" is not clear, so I think I can say, I seek the most suitable allocation that gives the lowest difference between the highest and lowest group observation numbers, with grouping only consecutive numbers without ties being on more than one group

What exactly are the requirements of this function? What if your data was all the same value? The more test cases you provide the easier it would be to know if the requirements can be satisfied.

@MrFlick
Sorry for the confusion, suppose this variable is the age and for some reasons, I want to split it into the most equal groups.
Of course, if the data was all the same value, I would not need to split it or use it as I think it is considered now constant.
Let me know if the question is still vague to edit it.

Most equal groups? Only that? ie Re you  grouping only consecutive numbers or any other value can be in any group?

@Onyambu
I am looking for a method to group consecutive numbers, similar to using cut-off points provided by quantiles. However, as I said I need to account for ties in the data as ties could not be in more than one group. I believe this can be achieved by iterating around the quantile values and trying different cut-off points until the most suitable grouping is found.
Is there a more elegant way or a specific function in R that can accomplish this efficiently?

You have 818 data points, for equal grouping each group can should have around 272 data points, You cannot do this when considering the data seems to be distributed as poisson with lambda around 31

@Onyambu sorry for my language. I do not really aim for equal allocation, as it is not feasible. Instead, I seek the most suitable allocation that gives the lowest difference between the highest and lowest group observation numbers.

Is it your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928710/sort-numbers-into-groups-so-that-the-difference-of-their-sums-is-minimal

@Ric
No, I want numbers to be consecutive meaning lowest numbers will be in the first group and highest numbers will be in the last group

If you want three groups of consecutive numbers with lower in first, then you wantn sorted numbers unless second group can have numbers smaller than the first, but then these are not consecutives. Also you want the same count for each group (not assured if you also want no ties across groups). It is ok?

@Ric
I mean to simplify the question suppose this variable is age. The goal is to achieve the most balanced categorization possible, meaning the difference between the highest and lowest group observation numbers should be minimized, even though it is impossible to achieve perfect equality. The groups should be in ranked order and if a specific value, like 35, is repeated multiple times, all instances of that value must be placed in the same group. For example, if the value 35 appears three times, and it is included in the first group, then all three instances of 35 must be in the first group

This script calculates all the possible groups and determine the cutting points that are "the most equal", understood as the cutting points to which the difference between the larger and the smaller group is minimal.
Such combinatorial aproach is only possible for moderate number of groups and data size. Otherwise, the task of determine the groups given the sums is NP hard (I do not known if it is in ordered cuts)
# Count and order the classes
tbl <- unclass(table(x))

# Enumerate the possible cutting points. There are 595 possibilities
cutting <- combn(length(tbl) - 1, 2)

# sum the nubmber of elements of each possible group
sums <- apply(cutting, 2, \(i) c(
  sum(tbl[1:i[1]]),        # From the minimal to the first cutting point (inclusive)
  sum(tbl[(i[1]+1):i[2]]), # from next to the first cutting point to second (inclusive)
  sum(tbl[-(1:i[2])])))    # from next to second to last

#check that sum of posible "sums" equals the sum iof tbl (818) 
stopifnot(all(colSums(sums) == sum(tbl)))

#calculate differnece between the largest and the smallest group
# as a metric of "most equal groups.
count_diff <- apply(sums, 2, \(i) max(i) - min(i))

#FINALLY: best cut points (inclusive)
print(names(tbl)[cutting[,order(count_diff)[1]]])
# 27 & 30
print(sums[,order(count_diff)[1]])
# 222, 318, 278

#second best  (and so on...)
names(tbl)[cutting[,order(count_diff)[2]]]

Data:
x = c(26, 34, 27, 26, 38, 40, 34, 28, 27, 36, 29, 30, 29, 44, 30, 
      34, 32, 30, 26, 29, 34, 32, 38, 27, 35, 29, 28, 34, 26, 27, 27, 
      30, 27, 28, 27, 28, 28, 27, 29, 29, 28, 29, 29, 28, 29, 29, 28, 
      27, 29, 27, 36, 34, 34, 39, 34, 31, 31, 33, 35, 31, 31, 32, 37, 
      38, 32, 31, 28, 33, 33, 28, 27, 27, 30, 31, 32, 28, 27, 31, 36, 
      27, 33, 31, 34, 31, 35, 38, 37, 36, 39, 33, 33, 28, 41, 34, 35, 
      37, 37, 41, 32, 37, 30, 34, 38, 30, 40, 35, 31, 30, 30, 29, 29, 
      30, 29, 35, 28, 27, 27, 27, 29, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 26, 28, 28, 
      27, 29, 29, 27, 27, 27, 27, 29, 27, 28, 27, 28, 34, 29, 28, 28, 
      28, 29, 38, 33, 39, 28, 27, 28, 27, 29, 34, 29, 32, 70, 26, 29, 
      43, 48, 30, 30, 27, 26, 29, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 
      27, 28, 28, 38, 52, 26, 31, 56, 29, 29, 36, 28, 35, 32, 34, 35, 
      28, 27, 37, 26, 26, 32, 26, 27, 30, 28, 28, 30, 29, 30, 29, 29, 
      28, 26, 33, 39, 26, 31, 27, 28, 30, 30, 28, 28, 29, 26, 27, 26, 
      29, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 29, 
      27, 26, 28, 28, 27, 27, 28, 27, 28, 28, 30, 27, 30, 28, 32, 34, 
      28, 27, 28, 28, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 28, 27, 27, 28, 27, 
      27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 27, 27, 27, 26, 27, 27, 30, 28, 27, 30, 30, 
      42, 26, 27, 40, 33, 29, 29, 29, 52, 58, 44, 32, 43, 30, 27, 38, 
      30, 27, 30, 27, 31, 39, 35, 32, 32, 34, 45, 31, 44, 42, 29, 29, 
      30, 30, 50, 30, 33, 31, 35, 27, 28, 27, 28, 55, 28, 28, 28, 27, 
      27, 28, 29, 27, 28, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 28, 29, 34, 45, 27, 
      29, 61, 38, 62, 29, 36, 36, 30, 31, 45, 27, 30, 28, 29, 44, 45, 
      42, 52, 50, 52, 42, 38, 42, 32, 27, 37, 40, 52, 27, 36, 38, 39, 
      34, 30, 29, 34, 29, 26, 35, 43, 33, 40, 35, 33, 41, 61, 45, 35, 
      52, 50, 38, 43, 29, 35, 38, 39, 31, 28, 28, 29, 34, 27, 30, 32, 
      28, 26, 28, 27, 26, 29, 27, 26, 29, 29, 27, 29, 27, 27, 29, 27, 
      30, 29, 25, 30, 27, 29, 29, 30, 30, 27, 30, 28, 28, 27, 29, 29, 
      30, 29, 27, 28, 28, 28, 29, 28, 28, 27, 28, 29, 28, 29, 27, 28, 
      28, 28, 30, 27, 27, 28, 26, 28, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 
      28, 27, 28, 27, 35, 27, 27, 28, 29, 27, 27, 28, 26, 27, 28, 28, 
      28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 32, 27, 28, 28, 29, 28, 28, 27, 28, 28, 30, 
      29, 28, 25, 27, 28, 30, 28, 30, 30, 28, 30, 30, 28, 29, 30, 28, 
      28, 26, 27, 28, 45, 36, 40, 28, 50, 45, 30, 45, 40, 30, 45, 45, 
      29, 45, 35, 40, 40, 30, 30, 30, 45, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 35, 
      34, 49, 40, 30, 61, 35, 40, 30, 36, 35, 29, 27, 48, 28, 27, 27, 
      26, 27, 29, 27, 26, 27, 31, 27, 27, 28, 29, 28, 27, 28, 29, 38, 
      30, 26, 36, 40, 58, 57, 30, 33, 56, 35, 39, 37, 38, 46, 37, 39, 
      39, 45, 35, 46, 58, 65, 60, 45, 32, 36, 43, 32, 68, 39, 28, 31, 
      27, 28, 27, 37, 38, 30, 30, 28, 36, 45, 28, 26, 28, 28, 28, 27, 
      26, 28, 27, 26, 26, 27, 28, 31, 32, 37, 35, 29, 33, 35, 29, 41, 
      32, 36, 29, 28, 28, 28, 37, 36, 37, 35, 31, 32, 30, 27, 31, 32, 
      31, 33, 28, 33, 29, 27, 28, 31, 28, 31, 28, 34, 27, 27, 28, 27, 
      27, 27, 27, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 28, 26, 31, 26, 29, 31, 29, 29, 
      30, 29, 30, 31, 32, 29, 30, 27, 32, 27, 26, 31, 31, 31, 27, 27, 
      33, 27, 28, 28, 28, 26, 27, 27, 28, 30, 27, 27, 30, 29, 26, 27, 
      28, 27, 26, 26, 28, 27, 26, 28, 28, 26, 28, 27, 29, 27, 28, 28, 
      26, 26, 29, 28, 27, 27, 27, 28, 26, 25, 27, 29, 30, 36, 40, 28, 
      38, 26, 27, 27, 50, 27, 45, 27, 28, 26, 25, 35, 35, 44, 30, 27, 
      31, 27, 28, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 35, 33, 30, 28, 28, 29, 29, 36, 
      32, 36, 34, 32, 28, 28, 29, 28, 28, 32, 30, 35, 33, 36, 32, 30, 
      32, 36, 34)


I create a function which takes a vector of numbers and break points, then calculates the length of each bin compared to the average bin size (total length divided by n, i.e. no. of breaks), and returns sum of the absolute differences between bin sizes and average bin size.
Then I can use optim to optimize that function and find the optimal break points. However, since optim is not designed to work with integers, I divide the break points and the vector (i.e. x) by 100 so it can reach the optimum easier.
fsplit <- function(param, xx, nn){
  l  <- cut(xx, breaks = c(-Inf, param, Inf))
  lt <- table(l)
  d  <- lt - length(xx)/nn
  return(sum(abs(d)))
}

m1 <- optim(c(28,31)/100, xx = x/100, nn = 3, fsplit, method='CG')

## optimal break points
floor(m1$par*100)
#> [1] 27 30

fsplit(floor(m1$par*100), x, 3)
#> [1] 101.3333

table(cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, floor(m1$par*100), Inf)))
#> (-Inf,27]   (27,30] (30, Inf] 
#>       222       318       278 

Benchmark:
Checking every possible break point works relatively fine for the OP's example, but for larger vectors, it will be really costly. See below;
Mdd <- function(x){
fsplit <- function(param, xx, nn){
  l  <- cut(xx, breaks = c(-Inf, param, Inf))
  lt <- table(l)
  d  <- lt - length(xx)/nn
  return(sum(abs(d)))
}
q1 <- quantile(x, probs = c(1/3, 2/3))
d1 <- 10^ceiling(log10(max(x)))
m1 <- optim(q1/d1, xx = x/100, nn = 3, fsplit, method='CG')
unname(floor(m1$par*d1))
}

Ric <- function(x) {
  tbl <- unclass(table(x))
  cutting <- combn(length(tbl) - 1, 2)
  sums <- apply(cutting, 2, \(i) c(
    sum(tbl[1:i[1]]),        
    sum(tbl[(i[1]+1):i[2]]), 
    sum(tbl[-(1:i[2])])))    
  stopifnot(all(colSums(sums) == sum(tbl)))
  count_diff <- apply(sums, 2, \(i) max(i) - min(i))
  return(as.numeric(names(tbl)[cutting[,order(count_diff)[1]]]))
}

TIC <- function(x){
  res <- combn(sort(unique(x)), 2, \(k)
    table(cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, k, Inf))), simplify = FALSE)
  as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(
    gsub("\\(|]|\\)", "", names(res[[which.min(sapply(res, var))]][2])),",")))
}

For the OP's vector, the performance is comparable:
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(Mdd(x), TIC(x), Ric(x), 
                               check = "identical")

Unit: milliseconds
   expr     min      lq      mean  median      uq      max neval cld
 Mdd(x)  3.2567  3.6213  4.611345  3.8095  4.1240  51.8633   100   a 
 TIC(x) 81.5470 85.7937 93.407666 91.9252 96.8024 169.0715   100   b
 Ric(x)  3.4082  3.7759  4.664426  3.9968  4.5983  16.9820   100   a 

But for a larger vector...
set.seed(123)
xx <- sample(15:200, 2000, replace = T)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(Mdd(xx), TIC(xx), Ric(xx), 
                               check = "identical", times = 20, unit = "ms")

Unit: milliseconds
    expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq      max neval cld
 Mdd(xx)    0.975    1.0793    1.24086    1.2914    1.3601    1.509    20   a  
 TIC(xx) 3179.531 3300.5153 3408.50612 3389.3137 3488.5846 3689.105    20   b 
 Ric(xx)  142.919  151.5047  176.46253  160.1243  165.8123  288.897    20   c


Update
If you want 3 groups only, you can try
res <- combn(sort(unique(x)), 2, \(k) table(cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, k, Inf))), simplify = FALSE)
res[[which.min(sapply(res, var))]]

which gives
(-Inf,27]   (27,30] (30, Inf]
      222       318       278


Older answer
This is not an intelligent approach but might help a bit, hopefully
n <- 2
lst <- c()
repeat {
    q <- quantile(x, probs = seq.int(n - 1) / n)
    if (!anyDuplicated(q)) {
        lst <- c(lst,list(table(cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, q, Inf)))))
    } else {
        break
    }
    n <- n + 1
}
lst[[which.min(sapply(lst, var))]]

which gives
(-Inf,27]   (27,28]   (28,30]   (30,35] (35, Inf]
      222       165       153       132       146


I want numbers to be divided into 3 groups, the problem with quantiles as I showed in the question is that they do not give the most balanced/qual groups because of ties, so I think I should not depend on them?

@NEA see my update
